# Monitor Database Calls with Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

So I've been reading through the Application Insights information published by Microsoft, and in particular this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-insights-search-diagnostic-logs/

So what I want to ask is, whats the most logical methodology to log database calls?

In my head, I want to be able to log into application insights, see the most common database calls being made, and see what their average call times are.  That way, I can say "wow the lookup to the membership profile table is taking a few seconds today, what's the deal?"

So I have a database name, a stored procedure name, and an execution time, what's the best way for me to take that data and store it in AI?  As a metric, an event, something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all AI has dependency calls autocollection. Please read [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-insights-dependencies/). Secondly it is planned to release SDK 1.1 next week. As part of that release there you will have DependencyTelemetry type that is added specifically for monitoring SQL, http, blob and other external dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @AnastasiaBaranchenkova. First of all, when you showed me the dependency information, my head almost exploded, that is awesome.  That being said, Im looking at some calls that I know have remote dependencies (web services and database calls), but I only see "No calls to remote dependencies were found", any ideas why this data wouldnt show?

Comment: What framework version do you use? It automatically collects everything starting from 4.6 (for async http it is 4.5.1). For earlier versions you need to install and configure StatusMonitor (that will enable AI profiler for w3wp process. Are we talking about web BTW?.. :) ). Check this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now/

Comment: Sorry for the delay @AnastasiaBaranchenkova in my response on this.  I downloaded AI via NUGET only a few days ago, Im using .NET Framework 4.5, and this is for a hosted web app out in Azure, so I attached AI to my project and published it.  As I hit my app I see a number of diagnostics store, but it's the remote dependencies that seem to not display at all... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Here is one more link that says how to add StatusMonitor for cloud apps: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-cloudservices/