# AppInsights not capturing dependency calls on hosted app, but works on dev machine

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have a solution composed of 3 web projects:

1 - `MVC` app used as auth/STS

2 - `Web Api 2` app

3 - `MVC` app (main site) used to load an Angular app.

I've downloaded all the nuget packages for `AppInsights` and everything should be configured correctly including having `<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector" />` in the `ApplicationInsights.config` file.

When I run my solution locally, I can see on the Azure portal that requests to my API are recording the dependency data (db queries). However, once I deploy to Azure, `AppInsights` records that a request was made to my API but it **does not** record the dependency data (querying the db, etc.), which is what I'm actually after because I need a benchmark so I can start enhancing performance for load/stress testing.

My current set up on Azure is that the main app (#3 above) is an `Azure Website` and the API as well as the auth app are hosted as virtual applications under the website.

Thanks in advanced for any help.

Comment: I've already looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121558/monitor-database-calls-with-application-insights/31125144#31125144 and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

What is .NET framework version you are using on Azure? Is it the same as in your dev environment?
App Insights collect this information starting .NET 4.6. If you are using 4.5, you should install Status Monitor or enable AI extension (see here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-asp-net-dependencies/)

Comment: It's 4.6 on both my dev machine and Azure.